# How to escape a single quote?

Tags: shell, sed, scripting, quoting, escape-characters

This works fine:

```
sed -i 's#    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a\[contains(@href,##' temp_spec.rb
```

against a source of

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(@href,'change_district')]").click
```

I am just left with:

```
'change_district')]").click`
```

but when I try to add a single quote at the end it fails:

```
sed -i 's#    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a\[contains(@href,\'##' temp_spec.rb

syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I am using `\'` to escape the single quote.

Note that I am using a `#` as a delimiter instead of the normal `/` delimiter as there are `/`'s in the text.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The strings inside single quotes are used verbatim by the shell (and hence cannot contain other single quote, since that would be treated as the closing one of a pair). That said, you have several options:

- end the single-quoted string, add escaped (either by backslash or double quotes) single quote, and immediately start the following part of your string:

  ```
  $ echo 'foo'\''bar' 'foo'"'"'bar'
  foo'bar foo'bar
  ```
- use double quotes for your string:

  ```
  $ echo "foo'bar"
  foo'bar
  ```

  this of course means that you have to be careful about what gets expanded inside the double quotes by your shell;
- if you are using utilities that understand `\xHH` or `\0nnn` escaping (GNU sed does), you can use one of those (ASCII single quote is at code point 39 (0x27), hence e.g. `\x27`).

Answer (score 1):

That syntax error there seems to be hinting at unescaped regex. I personally don't use sed that often, but if I remember correctly, you'll also need to escape things like parenthesis (and with double backslashes if you are using double quotes). [Here is a list of possible characters that you may need to escape...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400316)