# How to correctly use quotes in sed?

Tags: shell, sed, quoting

For example I want to change

```
"'this text'"
"that text"
'other_text'
```

into

```
'this text'
"that text"
'other_text'
```

I tried

```
sed -e 's/^"\'/"/g'
```

but my quoting must be off.

Ubuntu.

Comment: Probably because you forgot [How to escape a single quote ?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75988)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's|\x22\x27|\x27|;s|\x27\x22|\x27|' file
```

Output:

```
'this text'
"that text"
'other_text'
```

See: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: that is so Ugly

Comment: You gave me an idea. If you put those ugly numbers into shell variables, then you can use names i.e. `${single_quote}` `${double_quote}`, this is readable but more characters.

Comment: @richard: nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use escape `\` in a `''` quote. Therefore put everything in a `""` quote and escape the `"`s. e.g. `"s/^\"'/'/g"`

Alternatively end the `''` quote, do a `\'`, then start the `''` quote again e.g. `'s/^"'\''/'\''/g'`

Also if you are easily confused by the `\`s and `/`s, then note you do not have to use `/`s as delimiters. You can use any character, e.g. `"s%^\"'%'%g"`

---

This only does the first quote at the beginning of line, the bit you seem to be struggling on.

Comment: actually its the _second_ part that I'm struggling on

Answer (score 0):

Try this line

```
sed -e "s/^\"'/\'/g" -e "s/'\"$/\'/g" file
```

Instead of enclosing the `sed` expression between `' '`, do it between `" "` so you can escape with `\` the `" "`

e.g.

```
@tachomi:~$ echo "\"'this text'\""
"'this text'"
@tachomi:~$ echo "\"'this text'\"" | sed -e "s/^\"'/\'/g" -e "s/'\"$/\'/g" 
'this text'
```

e.g.2

```
@tachomi:~$ cat file.txt
"'this text'"
"that text"
'other_text'
@tachomi:~$  sed -e "s/^\"'/\'/g" -e "s/'\"$/\'/g" file.txt
'this text'
"that text"
'other_text'
```

Comment: You can do multiple `-e` in one `sed` e.g. `sed -e "s/^\"'/\'/g" -e "s/'\"$/\'/g" file`

Comment: first part of answer works but second part messes up output, unexpected token messages.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Try with the update

Comment: @MichaelDurrant could you please provide the output